# php is it possible to determine if a constant is user defined?

Tags: php

I know that in general I can check if a constant is defined with the following:

```
defined('MY_CONSTANT')
defined('PHP_EOL')
```

The first one is my own user-defined constant. The 2nd one is created by php.  Both can be checked with `defined()` and return a `boolean` value.

My question is.. is there a way to determine whether it is a user-defined constant or a php-created constant? For example, the `MY_CONSTANT` should return some equivalent of "user defined" and `PHP_EOL` should return some equivalent of "php-defined".

Comment: I cannot think of a reason you would need to do this at runtime.

Comment: I checked php.net/defined and even read the comments. And I followed related manual links. I see no indication that it is possible, but I wanted to confirm with the SO folks since they are ninjas.

Comment: @MartyWallace Also, I didn't ask if it had any use-cases; I asked if it was possible. It sounds like you just blew me off with a "you don't need to do this, but rtfm" response. Thanks.

Comment: Actually I was just curious what your reason for wanting to do this was in hopes of learning something useful today.

Comment: @MartyWallace I am building a php code parser of sorts, to categorize functions, classes, variables and constants used (using `token_get_all`). And I wanted to subcategorize the constants

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`get_defined_constants()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-constants.php) with a parameter of `true` to return a categorized array of all constants.

User-defined constants are under the *user* key:

```
print_r(get_defined_constants(true));
// outputs:
// Array (
//    [Core] => Array (
//      [PHP_EOL] => 1
//    )
//    [user] => Array (
//      [MY_CONSTANT] => 1
//    )
// )
```

Answer (score 1):

See get_defined_constants

http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-constants.php

```
$CheckConst = 'MY_CONSTANT';
$is_user_defined = isset(get_defined_constants (true)['user'][$CheckConst]);
```

Comment: Be careful doing this, it will not work in every PHP version.

Comment: @RPM: Can you clarify, what do you mean? In comment made in November 2013, your saying, that this might not work in every PHP version, while last [significant change to this function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-constants.php) (addition of `$categorize` parameters) was made with PHP 5.0.0, which was released in [July 2004](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP#Release_history), that is nearly **ten years before your comment**. What am I missing?

Comment: @trejder I'm not sure why I said that I can't remember now, sorry.

Comment: @trejder, I believe RPM is correct in his original statement. The function isn't the issue here, it is the syntax. Indexing the return value of a function with ()[''] supposedly doesn't work in every version of PHP, though I have never run into it myself.

Comment: @RalphRitoch Yes, you're right and thank you for reminding me this. I didn't notice that form of writing. My mind stopped at function name! :] Yes, you're correct -- this is fairly new way of using  function return, that is (if I'm not mistaken) available since PHP 5.4. I think, it wasn't even available in 5.3. Can't verify this now, because 5.4.7 is the lowest PHP version, that I use (and it works there of course).